# Show Class Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with a task where I need to derive the data type from the class, specifying and yen.

```
data Yen = Yen Integer

...
```

Comment: your code and description are both quite confusing. You have no class defined called `Currency`, although you do have a type called that. I suspect you're being asked to define a `Show` instance of the form `class (Show a) => Show (Currency a)` but that's not completely clear from your wording.

Comment: @RobinZigmond actually, `Currency` is not even generic, so the whole requirement `Show a => ...` seems useless...

Comment: Oops, not sure how I missed that @BlackBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a "clash" between the data constructors. You can omit the `Yen` and `Dollar` data types, and work with:

```
data Currency = Dollar Integer Int | Yen Integer
```

The `Currency` type constructor has no type parameter, hence `Currency a` makes no sense. What you probably want to do is write:

```
instance Show Currency where
    show (Yen y) = show y ++ "¥"
    show (Dollar d c)
        | c < 10 = '$' : show d ++ '.' : 0 : show c
        | otherwise = '$' : show d ++ '.' : show c
```